# Conditionally assign return value of functions in one line

Tags: ruby

Imagine I have the following two functions:

```rb
def myfunc
  puts "hello from myfunc"
  return "returned myfunc"
end

def myfunc2
  puts "hello from myfunc2"
  return "returned myfunc2"
end
```

And I want to conditionally assign the return value of these functions to a variable, while at the same time ensuring that both functions are called like so:

```rb
x = nil

temp = myfunc
x = temp unless x

temp = myfunc2
x = temp unless x
```

How can I reduce each two line assignment statement segment to one line?

Note, the following won't work because the second function won't get called:

```rb
x = nil
x ||= myfunc
x ||= myfunc2
```

Comment: what is the purpose of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Can `x` have an initial value other than `nil`?

Comment: And on the other hand: can the methods have a return value of `nil`? You might want to clarify why you want a _conditional_ assignment in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this but this is valid ruby code and both methods will get called

```
x ||= a = myfunc; b = myfunc2; a || b
```

Both methods are called but on first run of this line, `x` will always be assigned to return of `myfunc` so I don't understand the purpose of this code.

Or maybe you want a random assignment of a or b ?

```
x ||= a = myfunc; b = myfunc2; [a,b].sample
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [myfunc1, myfunc2].reduce { |f1, f2| f1 || f2 }
```

Unfortunately, the short notation would not work because of the necessity to imply short-circuit on `or`:

```
x = [myfunc1, myfunc2].reduce(:||) # does not work
```

Comment: The short notation doesn't work because `||` is not a method.

Comment: @Stefan ...and it’s not a method because of the necessity of short-circuit. `!@` is indeed a method.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean by _"necessity to imply short-circuit"_ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Hash:

`h = {f1: myfunc, f2: myfunc2}`

`x = nil`

`x ||= h[:f1]`

`x ||= h[:f2]`